# Let Wordpress to go opening an external URL

Tags: urls, links, cookies

I need to let my WP site go external with some links.

I've got this variable in function.php

```
$link=<a href=". $_COOKIE['link'] .">TEXT SHOWN</a>
```

Where $_COOKIE['link'] contains a certain link shown for every case I have to manage.

My code currently leads to this:
http://my_wordpress.com/link.com

But, instead I need to go to:
http://link.com

Comment: Hi, which function did you use to save the cookie data?

Comment: You're probably missing the protocol? i.e `http://` in your code, or while setting the `link` cookie. `esc_url($_COOKIE['link'])` would do it either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the "http" to the url

Try please this:

```
$link = "<a href='http://". $_COOKIE['link'] ."'>TEXT SHOWN</a>";
```

You also can adjust and add the http:// to the `$_COOKIE` itself.

If you want that the new link will open in a new tab, add `target='_blank'` like so:

```
$link = "<a href='http://". $_COOKIE['link'] ."' target='_blank'>TEXT SHOWN</a>";
```